# Flask Passing Arguments From One Html page to another

Tags: python, html, flask, parameter-passing

I am new to flask,HTML,Jinja and i am having trouble passing values from one template to another. Ive looked over many other pages on SO and nobody had quite the same issue. I have a page with a drop down select menu and a submit button which redirects the user once they've made their choice. My issue is that I do not know how to pass that choice to the form on the next page. The following is my HTML form code:

```
 <form method="POST" action="search">
            <div class="form-group" align="center">
                 <select class="vertical-menu">
                    {% for friend in strFriendList %}
                        <option name="friendToPay" value="{{ friend }}">{{ friend }}</option>
                    {% endfor %}
                </select>

                <a href="{{ url_for('payment') }}"  class="btn-primary"> Submit</a>
            </div>
 </form>
```

And the following are my search and payment functions:

```
    @app.route("/search")
def search():
  if "email" not in session:
    return redirect(url_for("login"))
  else:
    friendslist1 = Friendship.query.filter_by(username=session["username"]).all()
    friendslist2 = Friendship.query.filter_by(friendUserName=session["username"])
    strFriendList = [""]
    for friend in friendslist1:
      strFriendList.append(friend.friendUserName)
    for friend in friendslist2:
      strFriendList.append(str(friend.username))
    form = SelectFriendForm()
    return render_template("search.html",strFriendList=strFriendList,form=form)

@app.route("/payment",methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def payment(personToPay):
    form = PaymentForm()
    if request.method == "POST":
        if form.validate() == False:
            return render_template("payment.html", form=form)
        else:
            return render_template("search.html")
        # else:
        #     # Query the database and deposit the amount and subtract from giver

    return render_template("payment.html")
```

I want to get the friend selected in the search function sent to the payment function. Any help would be greatly appreciated, Thank You!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Starting with your HTML form. The `action` attribute of the form directs the form where to go on submission. Then you can just include a submit button for the user.

```
<form method="POST" action="payment">
    <div class="form-group" align="center">
        <select name="friendToPay" class="vertical-menu">
            {% for friend in strFriendList %}
                <option value="{{ friend }}">{{ friend }}</option>
            {% endfor %}
        </select>

        <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn-primary" />
    </div>
</form>
```

Then you can process it with something like this:

```
@app.route("/payment", methods=['POST'])
def payment():
    if request.form.get('friendToPay'):
        # Run your logic here

    return render_template("payment.html")
```

I've removed the form validation for the sake of clarity on the issue you're asking about.

Comment: Thank you, I will try this and give you best answer if it works

Comment: I don't understand how or why the page gets the actual value when using the <input> tag vs the  <a> tag but this works. thank you

Comment: The distinction is definitional. <a> is a simple link - just takes you from one place to another. <input> carries data with it by nature. Read more at https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_a.asp and https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_input.asp

Comment: Thank you so much great explanation